# How to change position of "Load Next Page" cell

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have ListView and ParseQuery.Adapter that show list of comments and my aim is to show new items at the bottom. I achieve this by adding to my query ascending order by key "createdAt" and calling method setStackFromBottom(true) on my ListView.

The only problem is that "Load Next Page" cell is shown at the bottom though it should be shown on top, cause I want show at first new comments, and then scroll to top to get the next page with older comments.

Is there a way of changing "Load Next Page" cell?